# sizeof object varies with context

Tags: visual-c++, windows-ce

In Win CE 6.0, class TankObject is defined in a static library, C++ compiler is VS2008; target is ARM4 (/QRarch4).

An instance of class TankObject is constructed by a call of the form

*TankObject myTankObject = new TankObject(parm1, parm2 ...);

Last attribute declared in TankObject definition is an object pointer, and when an assignment is made to same, memory corruption of another dynamically allocated object occurs.

Step into constructor reveals that operator new is called with a size of 0x500.   sizeof(TankObject) reveals two different values, depending on the context:

In instantiating context (the application), sizeof(TankObject) and sizeof(*myTankObject) is 0x500.
In context of the object itself (the constructor, or object methods), sizeof(TankObject) and sizeof(*this) is 0x508.  The address of last declared attribute is 0x500, relative to object.

The call to new requests and receives 0x500 bytes.   The object itself expects and uses 0x508 bytes, which can cause assignments to last attribute to step on other dynamically allocated objects.

Work around is to declare another unused attribute at the end of the object definition, to pad the request to new.

Both contexts include the same .h file, to debug I changed include statement to an explicit path name.  I also went through compiler switches, made them identical.   So I am puzzled, if any one can shed light, I'm glad, I would like to know a proper solution.

Comment: Somehow, compiler settings for the two projects differ in such a way that textually the same definition generates different binary layouts. Try to figure out the first (lowest-address) member that's out of place (at different offset from the beginning of the object in the two contexts). The issue will likely become obvious at this point, but if not, add the class definition to your question, and indicate which member is the first to diverge.

Comment: It is also possible that if you are `TankObject` has aligned members, that the heap allocated ones are not respecting the alignment attributes, thus explaining the difference in sizeof.

Comment: It is still not clear.  TankObject owns attribute struct PumpStatus.  Members of PumpStatus align between contexts, but attributes declared after PumpStatus misalign by 4:  TankObject scope puts attributes 4 bytes higher, access of last declared attribute is outside allocated memory.  Also of interest is that this overflow/misalignment is only in a Debug configuration link, in Release configuration, attributes are all within heap allocated space.

Comment: Adding __declspec(align(8)) to the first attribute with diverging alignment corrected sizeof and alignment.   Why it is necessary to tweak like this is not clear.